# Problema al cargar imagen en php

Tags: php, imagen, archivo

No se que estoy haciendo mal, intento restringir los archivos que quiero cargar..

```html
 <pre>
<?php
 
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
   $foto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
$archivo= $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$tipo= $_FILES["foto"]["type"];
$size= $_FILES["foto"]["size"];
$permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","application/PDF",image/jpg");
$limite_kb = 200;

if(in_array($tipo, $permitidos) && $size <= $limite_kb * 1024){
    echo 'si funciona ';
       } else{ 
     echo 'no funciona el tipo de datos';}
}
</pre>
```

Siempre me da el mismo resultado con cualquier archivo....

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te faltan unas comillas en `image/jpg"`

Comment: Para empezar fijate mostrando los pesos de las imagenes, yo estoy exactamente con eso en este momento y hay archivos que no me trae el peso por lo que pasa la condición del if  $size= $_FILES["foto"]["size"];

Comment: Si lo hice y me da el mismo resultado, incluso quite la condición del size y me da el mismo error..

Comment: Si haces un var_dump($_FILES) que sale? Es para ver qué recoge bien el archivo antes de procesarlo

Comment: Como dice @Carmen, deberías depurar con un `var_dump` lo que hay en `$_FILES`. También, aunque hagas la validación del lado del servidor, podrías limitar en el cliente el tipo de archivos permitidos usando **[`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)**, por ejemplo: `<input type="file" name="foto" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.png" />` de ese modo no permites que el cliente mande cualquier cosa al servidor.

Answer (score 0):

@A.Cedano `<input type="file" name="foto" accept="image/*" />` lo tengo el formulario, pero eso no impide que el usuario suba cualquier cosa a la aplicación, bastaría con clickear en la pestaña de "todos los archivos" y listo, haría un desastre. Pero tu consejo es valido.

@Carmen después de hacer el var_dump hice unos cambios:
(AND por &&) y las dos comillas del array $permitidos por comillas simples.

```html
<?php
 
 include 'conexion.php';
 
 if(isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $foto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
  $archivo= $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
  $tipo= $_FILES["foto"]["type"];
  $size= $_FILES["foto"]["size"];
  $permitidos = array('image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/gif','image/png');
  $limite_kb = 200 * 1024;

if (in_array($tipo, $permitidos) AND ($size < $limite_kb)) {

   echo 'si funciona <br>'.$limite_kb.'<br>';
   echo var_dump($tipo);
  } else{ echo 'no funciona el tipo de datos <br>'.$limite_kb.'<br>';
   echo var_dump($tipo);} 
?>
```

y funciona bien! Gracias a todos.